# Like hanging out with us? Come visit the chat!

Tags: discussion, chat

A little known fact to behold about the SE system is that **every** site has it's own chatroom!

Ours is named [**"The Screening Room"**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room)

If you ever want to discuss certain things you don't understand about the site but feel don't warrant a meta post, have a quick idea you'd like to discuss with the users and moderators, or just want to hang out and say how <strike>awful</strike> entertaining *Snow White and the Huntsman* is, drop on in!

@Iandotkelly, @NapoleonWilson, and @AnkitSharma are almost *always* idling in there, and discussing goings on about the site and our own banter so feel free to join us!

If you have any general questions on how the SE chat engine works, visit [The Chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq).

---

Note: You need at least 20 rep *anywhere* in the SE network to participate in chat.

**Related post:** [What is chat useful for anyway?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/892/what-is-chat-useful-for-anyway)

Answer (score 5):

The chat is more active again nowadays, this might be a good chance to bump this thread and maybe put it up on the Community Bulletin. (*hint* *hint*)

**Come visit us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room), talk about the newest movies, TV shows you are currently watching, this site and interesting questions or simply rant about the influx of ID questions.** ;)

I promise, most of us won't bite.

Comment: "most of us"... :)