# What is chat useful for anyway?

Tags: discussion, chat

*Note:  This is another of my Call To Arms series, you can see the others [***here***](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/724/please-use-the-flagging-system), [***here***](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/having-multiple-answers-can-be-a-great-thing), and [***here***](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/510/analysis-and-you-a-way-to-improve)

---

So what is this pesky chat button next to your user statistics preview useful for anyway?

[image]

StackExchange isn't the place for discussions!!!!!

Comment: Some background information on how/why this all started — [Do SE sites need a "third place"?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/)

Answer (score 12):

Actually, that is where you're wrong, good sir!

The [***chat***](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is **exactly** where users can go to discuss not only their questions and answers, but random theories, ideas, and other goings on that they feel they need to talk about!

In all seriousness, the chat feature here is a wonderful thing.  Instead of risking having a question closed on the main site, having an answer downvoted into oblivion, and instead of having your opinion destroyed/ignored on Meta if you're unsure of any of these.  Pop into the chat!

The purpose of the chat is to allow users to discuss items with the site, their own content, and whatever else may strike your fancy (wanna talk about DnD with your <strike>most hated</strike> favourite M&TV mods DForck & Tyler?  Come on down!  Want to know why @Nobby is secretly planning to overthrow us and take over the <strike>world</strike> site?  Come join us!

===

More importantly, want to know how to improve your answer/question before posting it?  Throw it in chat and ask for opinions.  The real-time chat allows us to help you if you need it.  Obviously, Meta is where we would prefer any actual questions about the site.  But chatting with users of the site and the moderators is a *great* staging area to fine-tune your question/answer/meta discussion before putting it before the rest of the community on the live site!

Yes the chat can get silent from time to time.  But maybe with enough enthralled users, we can keep the wheels turning :).

As always, the moderators are *constantly* in chat.  So even if you don't feel like being social, you can pop in and ask us site stuffs.

Comment: Hilarious. Very lucid writing mocking nobby :D By the way I did not know you hate @ian so much that you did not even bother mentioning his name (don't worry, your secret is safe with me). Would have upvoted it 1000 if only you have given me the power ;)

Comment: I think you have revealed the nobby's secret of talking over the word because he is like evil brother of  et who want to rule the earth but this secret will we remain with us too.Btw you forgot to mention our other mod name.

Comment: Ian doesn't play DnD that I know of :)  he is also considered the old man of the group so I'm waiting for him to kick us off his lawn

Answer (score 0):

By creating chat rooms related to film industries or type of movies like Comedy, horror on http://chat.stackexchange.com for movies. There are still not many chat rooms of MTV. But we wish to have more chat rooms for strong community.

1. We can have discussions related to specific movies and TV shows or some scenes in them.
2. We can have reviews from real people to movies and TV.
3. We can hold public to have chat topics in chat rooms. Because people like to discuss more about good and bad movies.
4. If any of questions not getting attention, then by pasting link of question in chat room we can draw attention to that questions.
5. We can easily discuss out off topic questions in chat and get answer.
6. Chat gives you motivation to visit site daily though you don't have questions. And you can make good friends over here.

We can use other site's chat room to advertise beta sites. There are 3 million people visiting on [stack exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/) sites. Many people are active in chats on network sites. Many of them are not knowing about this site. So we can attract that crowd by giving information of chat rooms here or specific questions already present on this site.

e.g I have [given information](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7006457#7006457) about chat room [Indian Movies](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6959/indian-movies) in [Indian Enthusiastic Programmers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13215/indian-enthusiastic-programmers) or by specifying any [question](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7005271#7005271)?

Comment: As per our current traffic. I don't think we need any more chat rooms. In future we can create as many room as per the requirement but i thing currently two rooms are enough.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Yeah... I am saying about future. If you are creating chat room, create chat room with full responsibility. And moderate it.